# htaccess RewriteCond using cookie value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using below code to redirect the site but its not working. Please suggest me how can I fix the issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site_mobile=desktop; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working? Did you check your browser to see if cookie is there?

Comment: Yes I have checked cookie is there and checked using php/jquery as well  but .htaccees is not fetching the cookie value..

Answer (score 0):

I think trailing `;` may not be always there. Try this regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|\s)site_mobile=desktop(;|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [R,L]
```

If that doesn't redirect try this condition (for testing):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} desktop [NC]
```